# etcd server output some error

Tags: etcd, etcd3

I started up with an etcdv3 single server, etcdctl get / put is ok but the server console has some error logs and how to fix it

```
2017-06-19 09:26:42.225787 I | etcdserver/api/v3rpc: grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::]:2379: connect: cannot assign requested address"; Reconnecting to {[::]:2379 <nil>}
2017-06-19 09:27:01.415397 I | etcdserver/api/v3rpc: grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::]:2379: connect: cannot assign requested address"; Reconnecting to {[::]:2379 <nil>}
2017-06-19 09:27:08.209185 I | etcdserver/api/v3rpc: grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::]:2379: connect: cannot assign requested address"; Reconnecting to {[::]:2379 <nil>}
2017-06-19 09:27:22.992708 I | etcdserver/api/v3rpc: grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::]:2379: connect: cannot assign requested address"; Reconnecting to {[::]:2379 <nil>}
2017-06-19 09:27:40.156845 I | etcdserver/api/v3rpc: grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::]:2379: connect: cannot assign requested address"; Reconnecting to {[::]:2379 <nil>}
```

server start script is :

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -p 2379:2379 \
  -p 2380:2380 \
  --name etcd-v3 \
  --volume=/data/docker/etcd-sigle-data:/etcd-data \
  quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.2.0 \
  /usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --name my-etcd \
  --data-dir /etcd-data \
  --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2379
  --listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2380 \
  --initial-cluster my-etcd=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-token \
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --auto-compaction-retention 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the trouble is related to connecting via ipv6. Try switching to ipv4 by specifiying proper IP address instead of `0.0.0.0` wildcard in `--listen-client-urls`.